# Question: Why do some people preface a question with "question"?

Tags: questions

Is it acceptable in the English language to do so? If so, what part of English would the first "question" be called...a conjunction?

Comment: I'd say it's just an idiosyncrasy they have or perhaps they want to draw attention to the fact that they require an answer. A Google search of the word _conjunction_ shows that it is used to connect clauses or sentences or to coordinate words in the same clause. So the word _question_ is not being used as a conjunction.

Comment: What about a discourse marker?

Comment: I'd say it's just what's left after "deleting" everything else from a "prefacing remark" (effectively, "discourse marker" as noted by @Dargscisyhp) along the lines of ***[I have a] question*** or ***[The] question [I want answered is]***.

Comment: It's almost like an interjection, grabbing the listener's attention similar to "Hey!".

Comment: Saying "Question" before actually saying your question would be an interjection.  (This is a comment, so it doesn't need to be researched.)

Comment: (I agree that it most closely fits the category of "interjection".  The purpose of saying "Question:" is to get the listener's attention and put his though processes in "question mode" so that he will be more likely to "get" the question the first time it's stated, and signal the listener that an answer will be expected.)

Comment: (Oops -- "thought processes")

Answer (score 2):

Saying "Question" before actually saying your question would be an interjection.

Comment: This is only a statement and there is no research behind it.

Comment: Hello, @Rick. Could you explain the logic you used to reach this conclusion and also include any research you may have done or cite references if available? Your answer is then likely to receive many more upvotes.